# Unable to load CSS and JS file after adding @REQUESTMAPPING annotation at class level

Tags: javascript, css, spring-mvc

I've added @RequestMapping annotation at class level for some views (jsp). When I try to access those pages with proper URL mapping, Pages displayed on but unable to render properly and it unable to load .js and .css files. In browser I get follwing error.
 GET 404 (Not Found)
where as in server log I get following messages.
org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound noHandlerFound
WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/ccb/invoice/webjars/adminlte/2.3.3/plugins/iCheck/icheck.min.js] in DispatcherServlet with name 'spring-dispatcher'.
Not sure why is thing hapening although static resources mapping at Servlet config file is perfectly fine and its loading for those pages which dont have @requstmapping annotation at class level.

Can you Please let me know where I making mistake.

```
@Controller @RequestMapping("/invoice") @SessionAttributes("ListOrderItems") public class InvoiceController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/index", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView adminPage() {
        System.out.println("Im in /Index** Mapping");
        String username;
        Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        username = auth.getName(); //get logged in username
        username.toUpperCase();
        // Logic to build menue based on the Role of the user.
        HashMap hm = new HashMap();
        OrderItems od = new OrderItems();
        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();
        model.addObject("usr", username);
        //Set the object for Menue Links on the Page
        model.addObject("mnue", hm);
        model.setViewName("index");
        model.addObject("odi",od);
        return model;

    } }


Dispatcher Servlet configuration file: <mvc:resources mapping="/webjars/**" location="/webjars/" />
    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
    <mvc:annotation-driven/>
    <bean id="viewResolver"
          class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"
>
        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/WEB-INF/jsp/</value>
        </property>
        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding xmlns in your  dispatcher servlet

```
xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
```

Then

```
<resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
    <beans:bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </beans:bean>
```